# How to set drag limit of canvas object in fabric js?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I want to set drag limit of canvas object so it not
move outside of clip area.  Here my clip area is shape
so please help me.

In this image you can see canvas area and clip area

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Here you can find solution :
On this solution I had included corner size to avoid object placed out of canvas while dragging, scaling.

var canvas = window._canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
canvas.selection = false;

fabric.Object.prototype.set({
    transparentCorners: false,
    cornerColor: 'red',
    cornerSize: 12,
    padding: 0
});
text = new fabric.Text('Sample',{
    top: canvas.height/2,
    left: canvas.width/2,
    fill: '#000000'
});

canvas.add(text);
canvas.setActiveObject(text);

canvas.observe('object:scaling', function (e) {
    var obj = e.target;
  if(obj.getHeight() > obj.canvas.height || obj.getWidth() > obj.canvas.width){
    obj.setScaleY(obj.originalState.scaleY);
    obj.setScaleX(obj.originalState.scaleX);        
  }
  obj.setCoords();
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top - (obj.cornerSize / 2) < 0 || 
     obj.getBoundingRect().left -  (obj.cornerSize / 2) < 0) {
    obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top + (obj.cornerSize / 2));
    obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left + (obj.cornerSize / 2));    
  }
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height + obj.cornerSize  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width + obj.cornerSize  > obj.canvas.width) {

    obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top - obj.cornerSize / 2);
    obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left - obj.cornerSize /2);    
  }
});

canvas.observe('object:moving', function (e) {
    var obj = e.target;
  if(obj.getHeight() > obj.canvas.height || obj.getWidth() > obj.canvas.width){
    obj.setScaleY(obj.originalState.scaleY);
    obj.setScaleX(obj.originalState.scaleX);        
  }
  obj.setCoords();
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top - (obj.cornerSize / 2) < 0 || 
     obj.getBoundingRect().left -  (obj.cornerSize / 2) < 0) {
    obj.top = Math.max(obj.top, obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top + (obj.cornerSize / 2));
    obj.left = Math.max(obj.left, obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left + (obj.cornerSize / 2));    
  }
  if(obj.getBoundingRect().top+obj.getBoundingRect().height + obj.cornerSize  > obj.canvas.height || obj.getBoundingRect().left+obj.getBoundingRect().width + obj.cornerSize  > obj.canvas.width) {

    obj.top = Math.min(obj.top, obj.canvas.height-obj.getBoundingRect().height+obj.top-obj.getBoundingRect().top - obj.cornerSize / 2);
    obj.left = Math.min(obj.left, obj.canvas.width-obj.getBoundingRect().width+obj.left-obj.getBoundingRect().left - obj.cornerSize /2);    
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jw1827fm/1/

Comment: Thanks Dear    it work for me but i ask to you getBoundingRect acquire area of rectangle canvas but my clip area is shape so it possible to implement in this code for shape

Comment: Hi Rajiv, Can i have your sample fiddle.?